# Google Hangouts Unable to Insert File in Hangout Conversation

Tags: browser

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong based on the message below? I was able to insert/attach a file inside of a Google Hangouts conversation, but when I try now this is what I get:

There was an error!
Details:
Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token)

I have logged in and out, rebooted, logged out of Chrome and signed back in.

Appreciate any help.

Thank you,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this feature today morning and realize that unfortunately this doesn't exist. The productsforum @ google is full of requests for this feature, see link below for your reference.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/hangouts/category$3Ai-have-an-idea$20file

I tried to drag and drop a music audio file on the chat window of the hangout browser and this is the error message that I received:

[image]

Per this image, it's obvious that hangouts only supports sharing of very specific image files as listed.